# android 6 marshmallow error code 506 when install app

Tags: android-version

android 6 marshmallow showing error code 506 when installing application from Google play store, 
i tried cache clean in Google play store and Google play service.
   Any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found fix, i have 2 GB free space in INTERNAL storage but when install app from SD card, it will show need storage free up some space. When install from Google Play Store it will show Error code - 506.

In android 6 , you can use your SD card as Internal storage ,but i just changed SD card as Portable storage. Now its install from SD card and Google play store.

So if you have problem in install app from Google play store with error code 506, change your SD card as Portable storage.

in android 6, change Portable storage goto Settings->storage and USB -> SD Cart-> click change format as Portable storage.(Keep in mind when format your data will lost so take backup)

Answer (score 0):

Change your setting mobile

Go to Settings -> Storage ---> preferred installation location ---> Let the system decide

more details [Refer Google Play Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/play/88-c72iczd0)

Comment: android 6 marshmallow don't have that settings, android 5 have that settings

Comment: do u tried in android version 6, in android 6 settings changed for storage , here u can't set "let the system decide", here you can only fix change SD as portable device. Settings->storage and USB -> SD Cart-> click change format as Portable storage. if you use SD card as internal storage some time you will base this error 506 when install app

Comment: Steps to change the Storage Setting:
Go to Setting >> Storage >> Preferred install location.
Tap on Preferred install location, a box will pop-up with different option.
Select “Let the system decide” option.

Comment: android 6 marshmallow that setting removed

Comment: I found this error in Android v5 and this fixed it.